# Networkx read from pandas creates 2 nodes for same source

Tags: graph, networkx

I'm trying to read in from a pandas dataframe using `from_pandas_edgelist` with the following code:

```
input = df_from_string("""
                 source, target,  size
                     abc,      xyz,    0.25
                     abc,      def,    0.35
                     xyz,      ghi,    0.40
          """)

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(input, source='source', target='target', edge_attr='size', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

The result I want is:

abc -> xyz -> ghi.

However currently I am only getting:

abc -> xyz

xyz -> ghi

Answer (score 0):

1. don't use names such as `input` for variables. This can be confused with python's input function.
2. check if the dataframe is loaded correctly (`df_from_string` doesn't seem to be a `pandas` function), so if you defined it yourself, either post it in your question for debugging, or verify that it does what it should do.
3. finally, if you post a problem with code, [make sure that the code that you post reproduces that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and doesn't throw other errors.

Meanwhile, if you generate the dataframe in a more standard approach:

```
import networkx as nx, pandas as pd, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'source': ['abc', 'abc', 'xyz'], 
        'target':['xyz', 'def', 'ghi'],  
        'size':[0.25,0.35,0.4]
    }
)
```

generating the graph works just fine:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='source', target='target', edge_attr='size', create_using=nx.DiGraph())[![enter image description here][1]][1]
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]